# Using brackets to select a list gives a two column list, how can I make it one column? Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

So here I have a function that takes the 'PPG' column from a table that is subset so it only shows points from rows where the passed (era) value is equal to the players' era (basically just filtering for a specific era).

```py
def points_by_era(era):
    return [sca_raw[sca_raw['Era'] == era]['PPG']]
```

So when I pass 2000 into this function, it returns this list.

```
[2      36.198171
 5      29.802555
 9      22.629905
 130     2.750000
 131    13.124230
 132    19.550000
 133     3.550000
 134     2.523333
 135     2.523333
 136     3.406667
 137     6.610000
 138     6.069000
 139     4.285000
 140     5.029500
 141    10.790000
 142     2.006667
 143     9.580000
 144    19.550000
 145    13.270000
 146    20.250000
 147     1.020000
 148    14.570000
 149     4.125000
 150    14.740000
 151    15.790000
 Name: PPG, dtype: float64]
```

For whatever reason, this looks like two columns, and when I make a dictionary and try to make a dataframe from said dictionary, it returns a table where something is clearly wrong.

```
dict_of_ppg = {'1960': points_by_era(1960),
               '1980': points_by_era(1980),
               '2000' : points_by_era(2000),
               '2020': points_by_era(2020),
               '2040' : points_by_era(2040),
               '2060': points_by_era(2060),
               '2080': points_by_era(2080),
               '2100' : points_by_era(2100),
               '2120': points_by_era(2120),
               '2140': points_by_era(2140),
               '2160' : points_by_era(2160)}
ppg_by_era = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_of_ppg)
ppg_by_era
```

[Here is the returned table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb5eG.png)

And if I attempt to draw a boxplot with one boxplot per dictionary entry, I get this error.

```
plt.boxplot(dict_of_ppg)
plt.title("Distribution of Scoring Value Through Time")

...
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I think this has something to do with the index that is in the original table, can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Era':[100,200,100,200], 'PPG':[1,2,3,4]})
def points_by_era(era):
    return df[df['Era'] == era]['PPG'].values
dict_of_ppg = {'100': points_by_era(100),
               '200': points_by_era(200)}
pd.DataFrame(dict_of_ppg)
```

output:

[image]

And plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.boxplot(df)
```

output:

[image]